# Identity column changes after every savechanges in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am doing an update in EF Core. In this update process, I have objects that take multiple objects.

But after each `savechanges` operation, the primary key Identity field in the relevant table is updated in a changed way, and because it changes the Id fields, it performs the update process in a confused manner in the data I added.

This is how I get my data, which comes as an example, in the form of a list.

```
var vPrecondition = issueInfo.IssuePreconditionInfos.Select(x => new IssuePrecondition
                {
                    LineNo = x.LineNo,
                    Explanation = x.Explanation,
                });
```

Then I transfer it like this.

```
vIssue.IssuePreconditions = vPrecondition.ToList();
```

My data and transfer operations with EF Core are as follows.

My example code:

```
var vIssue =  _context.Issues
                          .Include(x => x.IssueActivitiys)
                          .ThenInclude(x => x.IssueActivitiyDetails)
                          .Include(x => x.IssuePreconditions)
                          .Include(x => x.IssueNotes)
                          .Include(x => x.IssueRelevantDepartmants)
                          .Include(x => x.IssueAttachments)
                          .Include(x => x.IssueRoles)
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == issueInfo.Id);
                       
                        vIssue.TitleId = issueInfo.TitleId;
                        vIssue.SubtitleId = issueInfo.SubtitleId;
                        vIssue.Summary = issueInfo.Summary;
                        vIssue.Status = ActivityStatuses.Processing;
                        vIssue.IssueActivitiys = vIssueActivitiys.ToList();
                        vIssue.IssueNotes = vIssueNote.ToList();
                        vIssue.IssuePreconditions = vPrecondition.ToList();
                        vIssue.IssueRelevantDepartmants = vRevelantDepartment.ToList();
                        vIssue.IssueRoles = vIssueRole.ToList();
                       
                        vIssue.IssueNo = 0;
                        vIssue.VersionNo = 0;
                        
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Before the above action takes place

```
Id    Summary
474   foo
475   bar
476   example
```

was taking place

But after `savechanges`

```
Id    Summary
477   bar
478   foo
479   example
```

takes place in the form

My FluentApi model Configuration setting and my Precondition table's configuration setting just for example.

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IssuePrecondition> modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ToTable("IssuePrecondition");

            modelBuilder.Property(e => e.Explanation)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasComment("Açıklama");

            modelBuilder.Property(e => e.IssueId).HasComment("Konu Id");

            modelBuilder.Property(e => e.LineNo).HasComment("Satır No");

        }
```

How can I ensure that my Id fields do not change during the update process or how can I prevent my data from changing after `savechanges`?

Comment: You say "primary key identity" but sometimes people say that when they have an identify field that may or may not be an actual primary key. Identity and primary key are not the same, and you can have either one without the other. Please show how you've configured the *primary key* in the model.

Comment: EF doesn't update keys by itself. You didn't post your DbContext configuration or provided sample data, so it's hard to know what class/table you're talking about or how the ID is configured- an IDENTITY field can't be updated to begin with. Your code though does some *strange* things - even though you eagerly load related entities, you discard them and replace them with completely new objects. Are you confusing the new objects for updated older ones? It's *your code that deletes the old objects and creates new ones*

Comment: Id field is set to primary key and autoIncrement. Are you saying that?

Comment: Are you sure those aren't *new* records? Your code is removing all old related records and replacing them with new ones. Those new objects have no ID themselves, so EF can only treat them as new objects

Comment: Exactly. While updating the record, it deletes the old record and updates the new record by creating a new Id instead.

Comment: So when are you going to show the model configuration? Or are you just going to continue arguing the same points?

Comment: I think you wanted the fluentapi configuration setting and I added it as edit at the end.

Comment: @CelalPoyraz that configuration shows no key, much less an IDENTITY

Comment: @CelalPoyraz what do you mean `exactly`? That's what you told the code to do - delete all old records and replace them with new ones. If you don't want that, don't do that. What are you trying to do in the first place? Update the existing records with new values? Don't replace the old records then. You'll have to update each one with values from the matching object in your lists

Comment: Nor does it show the columns related to the data that you showed (`Id`, `Summary`).

Comment: While updating the record first in my code, as you said, the record is updated after the decision is made first. I want the record to update my new record.I think I may have a hard time being understood because my English is not very good :)

Comment: English is not the problem. You keep repeating things that don't matter or provide meaningful details. You haven't posted configuration relevant to the issue at hand. I don't know how you expect to get help if you can't provide the information needed to give you that help.

Comment: @CelalPoyraz it's not a matter of English. Your code isn't doing what you think it does. Your code says "delete those records and add these new ones". There's no way for EF or even a human to guess that you actually wanted to update the older records. Even if someone guessed that, how could they find which rows to update, when there's no ID in the code? In the `Precondition` class there's a `LineNo`,not an ID. If `Issues.Preconditions` has 100 items, which of them should be updated from the new object with LineNo=1134 ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to your new row exactly get the next number you should be careful that:

- Identity column was change with every transaction even that transaction not successful.
- then you should check all validation before call `SaveChange`
- also you if you want exactly get next number you should create a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction but I not advice to do this at all
- If you want the place of your data not changing in Table you should change your ClusterIndex

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ListingData> builder)
{
   builder.HasKey(e => e.Id).IsClustered(false);
   builder.HasIndex(e => e.code, "ix_code").IsClustered(true);

}
```

Comment: No, my problem is that after the update, both my Id field changes and the places of my data in other columns are changed.

Comment: but I'm the Id field and I want my data not to change places

Comment: you should change your cluster index

Comment: This is all beside the point. See the comments above.